Transform not working for non-square images using scipy griddat and cv2.remap
I am optimizing a match between two sets of points on an image, once I have the points I use the following function to transform the image.
def smudge(src_im,src_pts,dst_pts):
    h=src_im.shape[0]
    w=src_im.shape[1]
    grid_x, grid_y = np.mgrid[0:w-1:w*1j, 0:h-1:h*j]
    
    # Add corners of image so the remap will transform the whole image
    corners = np.array([[0, 0], [0, h], [w, 0], [h, w]], dtype=np.float32)

    src_map = np.vstack((src_pts, corners))
    dst_map = np.vstack((dst_pts, corners))

    grid_z = griddata(dst_map, src_map, (grid_x, grid_y), method='cubic')
    map_x = grid_z[:, :, 1].astype('float32')
    map_y = grid_z[:, :, 0].astype('float32')

    out= cv2.remap(src_im, map_x, map_y,cv2.INTER_CUBIC, borderMode=cv2.BORDER_CONSTANT,borderValue=0)

    return out

The optimization is done on a square image. I want to apply the function on the same image with different sizes. I apply a linear transformation to the points and use the function to apply it to other image sizes.
The problem is it works only for square images, if I try to stretch the image in any direction (also applying the stretch to the points) I get a different result.
What am I missing?? (tried swapping the H W, transpose...)
